How can you save/look at the information in a dendrogram?
I am trying to analyze data to determine the outcome based on a dendrogram. The problem is that I have primarily 2 groups of data "H" and "U", both of which are analyzed together. At the end of the dendrogram, I need to know which area has more "H" and "U".
I tried using the dictionary information of the dendrogram, but when I opened the functions I noticed that at no point does it contain the information I put in through linkage.
The following is the code I'm using:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage, set_link_color_palette
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df=pd.read_csv(name+".csv", index_col=None, header=0)

normalized_df=(df-df.mean())/df.std()

pca=PCA(n_components=6, n_oversamples=6)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(df)
principalDF = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2', 'principal component 3', 'principal component 4', 'principal component 5', 'principal component 6'])

#Adds the type (U/H) to the dataframe
finalDF = pd.concat([principalDF, full_df[['type']]], axis = 1)

#From here on is when I start to have problems
data = list(zip(finalDF['principal component 1'], finalDF['principal component 2']))

linkage_data = linkage(data, method='ward', metric='euclidean')
hierarchy.set_link_color_palette(['r','g','b','w'])
den=dendrogram(linkage_data)
plt.title("Attempt #1")
plt.show()

The dendrogram looks as expected. The problem is that I am unable to differentiate the type (H or U) of each point.
As mentioned, I attempted to look at the properties of the dendrogram, such as icoord and dcoord, but I couldn't figure out what it meant.
The data itself I'm using is 6 different columns, with different numbers which is the data I normalize ((df-df.mean())/df.std), and then take the principal components.
Any advice?
Edit: Here is an example of the data I have:

And here is a picture of the dendrogram, using the first 2 principal components:

The idea in this case would be to be able to differentiate which points are H and which are U.
It is important to note that this is just an example, as the real data set I am using contains about 20,000 rows, and ends up having 3 different colors. I am using a short version of the data to try different things with the code.

please add some images to show what you mean, with some markers drawn preferably to point at the artefacts you expect (like U vs H differentiation)
